# Not convinced by condition for converg. in prob. $\implies$ converg. in mean.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I've found an exam question which gives a sufficient condition for the implication $X_n \overset{P}{\rightarrow}X \implies X_n \overset{L_1}{\rightarrow}X$, but I have a counter example which seems to disprove it.

The condition reads, if there exist $M>0$ and $N \geq 1$ such that for all $n\geq N$ then $P(|X_n| \leq M)=1$. If we have such an $X_n$, then convergence in probability implies convergence in mean.

My counterexample is the somewhat known one $X_n \sim unif(0,n)$ or $f_n = \frac{1}{n}\chi_{[0,n]}$ which converge to $0$ in probability but not in mean. For this example we can take something like $M = 1$ and $N = 2$. Then for all $n\geq 2$ we have 
$$P\left(\frac{1}{n}\chi_{[0,n]} \leq 1\right) = 1.$$
Is the condition not stated properly, or did I make a mistake with my reasoning?

Comment: For convergence in mean or probability, one assumes that all random variables are on the same sample space. Your counterexample can be seen as a collection of functions on an infinite measure space, or as defined on a different measure space for each function.

Comment: Don't you mean $P\left(|X_n|\leq 1\right) = 1$ instead of $P\left(\frac{1}{n}\chi_{[0,n]} \leq 1\right) = 1$ at the end? Typo?

Comment: @SergioParreiras: If I'm not mistaken the two should be equivalent.

Comment: @B.Mackey: In that case, what would be an example of an $X_n$ which converges to an $X$ in probability, but not in mean?

Comment: @BallzofFury, consider $X_n= n \chi_{[0,1/n]}$ defined on $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I see what you mean, I was just trying out $\frac{1}{1-n}x^{-n}\chi_{[0,1]}$. Thank you very much for your help, I think I'll be able to continue with the rest now.

Comment: The "counterexample" confuses random variables (functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$) with their densities (functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R_+$). The latter are bounded but not the former, and the condition is that the former are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an outline for the proof:

Suppose $X_n \to 0$ in probability without loss of generality, and suppose $|X_n| \leq M.$ Then given any positive $\epsilon,$

$\int_{\Omega} |X_n| dP \leq M P(|X_n| > \epsilon) + \int_{\Omega} \epsilon dP.$

Comment: This proves the classical condition but the OP asked whether their counterexample was valid or not hence I fail to see how this answers the question. Having said that, I see that the OP accepted this answer, which shows once again that premature acceptances are a plague and that quite a few aspects of this universe elude me...

Comment: He provided me with the reason for which it wasn't valid in the comments. EDIT: Sorry about that, I see what you mean with your additional comment. Thank you for making the distinction more clear.